# How to disable the editing of the time and date published for particular post type only?

Tags: custom-post-types

[How to disable the editing of the time and date published?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71608/how-to-disable-the-editing-of-the-time-and-date-published)

This working fine for me but it's disabling all the time-and-date-published.I need to apply for one particular custom post type.some one please help on this

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a conditional if loop inside that?

```
function deny_post_date_change( $data, $postarr ) {

    $your_post_type = "post";

    if( $data["post_type"] == $your_post_type ) {

        unset( $data['post_date'] );
        unset( $data['post_date_gmt'] );
        return $data;

    } else {

        return $data;

    }

}
add_filter( "wp_insert_post_data", "deny_post_date_change", 0, 2 );
```

Comment: But How can i remove from UI @Anteraez.css part

Comment: @Musni Please check my other answer and let me know if that's what you want, and whether it is working for you.

Comment: If i  put if condition , when i edit other post i'm getting error message like this                      **The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.**

Comment: @Musni It was an error on my side. I have corrected the code and also tested it on a local wordpress install. Instead of using add_action, it had be add_filter.

Comment: Thank you very much it's working for me

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to remove the **Publish: XXXXX** from the sidebar like the images below.

[image: UI with Publish Date Picker Option]

TO the one below without the **Publish: XXXXX**

[image]

To do this, you would need to create a CSS File and add some code to your theme's functions.php file, or your plugin's file.

The CSS File will have the following code,

```
.edit-post-post-publish {
    display: none;
}
```

Name the css file **delete-published-on-from-gutenberg.css** and place it in the css folder in your theme, or plugin.

Next, you need to add the following code to the theme's function.php file or the plugin's file.

```
function delete_published_on_from_gutenberg() {
    $your_post_type = "book"; // Change this to your post type.
    $current_post_type = get_current_screen();

    if($current_post_type == $your_post_type) {
        wp_enqueue_style( "delete-published-on-from-gutenberg", get_template_directory_uri() . "/css/delete-published-on-from-gutenberg.css", array(), "1.0" );
        // Replace get_template_directory_uri() . "/css/delete-published-on-from-gutenberg.css" with plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . "css/delete-published-on-from-gutenberg.css" if you are creating a plugin.
    }
}
add_action( "enqueue_block_editor_assets", "delete_published_on_from_gutenberg" );
```